# How to implement text boxes with multiple options like people app at runtime in uwp app?

Tags: xaml, menu, uwp, uwp-xaml, flyout

I am developing a UWP app and I have to make a control like in the People app for Windows 10.

[image]

I am currently trying this

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="stp">
            <Button Content="Button 1" x:Name="btnAction1">
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Action 1" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click">
                        </MenuFlyoutItem>

                    </MenuFlyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

and in c#

```
 private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnAction1.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);
        stp.Children.Add(new TextBox() { Name = "newTxtBox", Text="Tushar"});
    }
```

But this will end up handling UI too much with no animation at all. I want to give an option to the user to remove this dynamically created control.

After that I would want something like this:[Dynamically adding textboxes with animation and option to close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlnMm.png)

Can anybody please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You might want to review the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on how a question might be better formed to solicit a helpful response. As it currently sits your question is pretty broad and seems to basically ask for someone to do your work for you. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of [Flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/dialogs) and use the LightDismissOverlayMode property to suit your scenario. If any particular UI specific implementation required, post a screenshot.